# How to override the @NotNull HTTP Status Code from 400

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I'm working on creating a new SpringBoot API and I have a few mandatory parameters in my Model. For example

```
@NotNull(message="Name is Mandatory")
public String Name
```

Whenever Name is not provided, it currently returns a status code 400 Bad Request with the defined message. Is there a way to override the Status Code from 400 to 404 Not found?

Comment: Try to use ControllerAdvice to handle the thrown exception and return 404 response

Comment: I think you can let it throw such that exception and handle it in your RestControllerAdvice file by your @ExceptionHandler method when its message is what you expect